How to configure and make an API call to workday from Snowflake
I have a use case to generate a JWT and use that to make an API call to workday from snowflake. Any suggestions?
I am able to achieve this using Azure data factory, but exploring the possibilities to directly make a call using snowflake instead of ADF.

Having read the documentation regarding making api calls from Snowflake, what’s the specific issue you need help with?

You can use snowflake external access integration to make API calls. You can write your logic using a python stored procedure.
A sample example for the same can be found in the snowflake documentation - here
